# How To Split Strings With Delimiters That Count Data In Python

Tags: python, string, split

It's the first time I am writing here, and I don't know how to solve this.

Basically, I want to split a large string with multiple delimiters. The delimiters are not commas, tabs, or anything like that. This string is delimited by four digits; the first two describe what kind of data it has, and the last two describe how long the data is, so it's something like this:

PN1121 E 1st St0008New York0102NY020510003

Where PN is the address and 11 is the number of characters it has, the next is 00, which means city, and 8 is the number of characters it has; the next is 01, which means state and has 2 characters; and so on.

My problem is finding a way to extract this data and split it into commas like this: 21 E 1st St, New York, NY 10003. And not only that, but there will be some data that the string will not have, so it will be something like this:

PN1121 E 1st St0102NY020510003

And in those cases, it should be replaced with a space like this: 21 E 1st St, NY, 10003

I have been struggling with this a lot. Can anyone help me? I won't attach the string because it's just too long, but you can get data like: PN, 00, 01,..., 40, 41.

I have tried this in Python, but I'm not going to lie; programming is not my forte, and I only know some very basic Python. Can you teach me via Python?

Comment: The best way to learn is to do some language tutorials and then start writing code. To get help here you need to post the code that you have tried first. Show the error message or results it produces and show the desired results you expected. For this problem, check out the [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method for strings.

Answer (score 2):

When you are facing a problem that looks too hard, try to split it in smaller parts, and solve it calmly part after part.

What do we have here? A number of strings composed of sequences of *id, length, data* in a well defined but non standard format, and you want to build a csv with all that. Interestingly enough you know the list of possible ids.

Let's go step by step...:

1. Given a simple data element, extract its type identifier, its length and data:

   ```
    typid = s[0:2]        # typ is contained if first 2 characters
    length = int(s[2:4])  # data length is contained in next 2
    data = s[4:4+length]  # get it
   ```

   not harder than that...
2. Given a full string, iterate over its tokens:

   Before going further, we should notice that above code will extract the first token from the full string, and that next token, will start at position `4 + length`. We could easily build a list of (typid, data) by iterating over the string:

   ```
    linedata=[]              # initialize an empty string
    pos = 0                  # start at the beginning
    while pos < len(s):      # and step over the string
        typid = s[pos:pos+2]          # typ is contained if first 2 characters
        length = int(s[pos+2:pos+4])  # data length is contained in next 2
        data = s[pos+4:pos+4+length]  # get it
        linedata.append((typid, data) # append what we have found to the list
        pos = pos + 4 + length        # and go the thee beginning of next token
   ```
3. Build a csv file from all that:

   Python is a *batteries included* tool. As soon as you have a sequence of key, value pairs, you can convert it to a `dict`, and the csv module contain a `DictWriter` class to build a csv from dicts. And as you know the possible identifiers, you can ask it to write it as a csv header line. I will not provide code for that part, because you have not given where you data come from, but it should not be too hard.

What you should have learned:

When you are facing a complex problem, try to split it in smaller parts. No only you will probably be able some parts alone, but you could ask here more precise questions, and expect detailed and complete answers. But do not forget to give also the general context...

Answer (score 0):

I try to use simple and direct code to solve the question. Followed by an explanation of the code.

```
def delimite(string):
    count = 0  # count stands for the delimeters. When count == 4, we get a complete delimeter
    length = 0  # length used to store the length of each data
    number = ""  #  number used to store the delimeters
    result = "" 
    for letter in string:
        if length == 0:  # if length == 0, it means we are in process of extracting the delimeters
            count = count + 1 
            number = number + letter  # store the delimeters
            if count == 4:  # if count == 4, it's time to get a delimeter
                length = int(number[2:])  # extract the last two digits
                number = ""  # empty number and count
                count = 0
        else:  # if length != 0， we are in process of extracting the data
            result = result + letter  # store the data one by one
            length = length - 1 
            if length == 0:  # length == 0 means we finishing storing current data, and we add a ", " 
                result = result + ", "
    result = result.rstrip(", ")  # using the rstrip method to remove the last ", "
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
def parse_data(input_string):
    data = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(input_string):
        length = int(input_string[index + 2:index + 4])
        index += 4
        current_data = input_string[index:index + length]
        data.append(current_data)
        index += length
    return data

input_str = "PN1121 E 1st St0008New York0102NY020510003"

parsed_data = parse_data(input_str)
print(parsed_data)
```

Output:

```
['21 E 1st St', 'New York', 'NY', '10003']
```